# Android TableLayout - span element across two rows

Tags: android, tablelayout

I'm using TableLayout to positon some buttons, I'd like to span Button 2 across 2 rows, so it would be next to buttons 1,3.
[image]

I know it can be done with grid/relative layout but I need to make it work with table layout.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 3" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: you got any solution for this?

Comment: You can't do it directly using TableLayout, you can take one row and give it twice the weight, than insert another layout there that gives you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can span 2 rows using TableLayout inside TableLayout. Check my code :

```
<TableLayout
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Column 1" />

        <TableLayout>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Column 2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Column 2" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: the thinking is help me, +1,  though, I do not use your layout. But use your thinking Thanks.

Comment: a linear layout in a table row inside, may achieve lot.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this live, but I have similar code that performs the same thing within a table layout, so pretty sure you can do this if you wrap Button 1 and Button 2 in a LinearLayout (within TableRow1):

```
   <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <Button
       android:id="@+id/button1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Button 1" />
      <Button
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Button 2" />

    </LinearLayout>

   </TableRow>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My application has a few more buttons, using that method would create a pretty messed up layout, I'd have to encapsulate 2 rows of my table layout to achieve that result.

Comment: Understand (that's real life after all), but that wasn't specified in question, so I provided best/simplest/quickest answer I could.